# How to change the element of array in swift

Tags: swift

I'm having difficulty with this function:

```
func sort(source: Array<Int>!) -> Array<Int>! {
   source[0] = 1
    ......
    return source
}
```

An error happens:

[image]

Why can't I directly assign the value to the specific element in the array?

Comment: If you want to modify the array that was passed in, add the `inout` keyword: `func sort(inout source: [Int])` and call it like this `sort(source: &myArray)`.

Comment: Be aware that the code crashes if `source` is `nil` or empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `sort` is immutable because it's a parameter. You need to create a mutable instance. Also, there's no reason to have the parameter and return value as implicitly unwrapped optionals with the `!` operator.

```
func sort(source: Array<Int>) -> Array<Int> {
   var anotherSource = source // mutable version
   anotherSource[0] = 1
   ......
   return anotherSource
}
```

Comment: and the preferred way to write `Array<Int>` is `[Int]`

Comment: It's more common to write it as `[Int]`, yes. Although in some rare circumstances `Array<Int>` does make sense.

Comment: Generic never be nil?

Comment: If you leave off the `!` then it's never nil and it's much safer.

Comment: Thanks, my memory is in swift1.

Comment: Avoid implicitly unwrapped `Optional` and force-unwrapping `Optional` as much a possible. Using them is a good way to shoot yourself in the foot.